# In an alt row color html table, how could I color a few columns different

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I have a html table and I am using alternative row colors (white and gray).

I now added a few more columns and I want to show that certain columns are grouped together so I colored the backcolor light green.  The issue is that the alt row coloring looks weird as its not applied to those new green columns.

Is there anyway someone can think of a solution where I can change those columns to green but it still keep that alternative color affect on those columns?

Comment: maybe showing a jsfiddle of it, can help us help you better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
<table border="1">
    <tr class="even">
        <td>stuff</td>
        <td>stuff</td>
        <td>stuff</td>
        <td>stuff</td>
        <td class="special">stuff</td>
        <td class="special">stuff</td>
        <td>stuff</td>        
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
        <td>stuff</td>
        <td>stuff</td>
        <td>stuff</td>
        <td>stuff</td>
        <td class="special">stuff</td>
        <td class="special">stuff</td>
        <td>stuff</td>        
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

```
.odd{
    background-color: gray;   
}

.special{
    background-color: #9999ff;   
}

.odd .special{
    background-color: #7777ff;   
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ycdSr/

Just make the intersection a color that is similar to both colors combined.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a matter of order of operations.  Do the alternating colors and then do the shading of the columns you want to group together changing the colors of those columns from the alternating to the shading colors.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of light colours, you could use dark colours with a transparency value, so your grey background would be for example black with 90% transparency and your green would be dark green with 80% transparency (rgba values for modern browsers or png images with IE6 fix for older browsers).

That way, the green column would show the grey background below it, making it slightly darker green on the grey rows.

**Edit:** As a test in a modern browser you can use for example `rgba(0,0,0,0.2)` as your grey value and `rgba(0,255,0,0.3)` for your green value. Just see how it looks and if it works, you can fix it for older browsers as well.

Some more information about [browser support](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/) for `rgba`.

And to [make it work in IE8-](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#rgba).

Comment: i think i like your idea but don't fully follow.  Are you suggesting the same thing as kingjiv or something else ??  Do you have any examples of this

Comment: @ooo The result should look similar, but kingjiv is using absolute colour values and I would suggest using rgba values (colours with a transparency value) so that it is easy to change one colour without having to change the rest as the transparency will take care of colours on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

well if you give them a class you should also give the class the right css attributes and values, like Avitus says